# Haskell IO - file lines to list

Tags: list, haskell, io

I am writing a haskell program and am having trouble with IO types. It seems something is wrong with my readLines function and the type it is supposed to return. I want it to return a list where each element is a line from the file that is opened with the openDict function.

Here is my code.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    fileHandle <- openDict
    readLines fileHandle
    putStr "End of program\n"

readLines :: Handle -> [IO String]
readLines fileHandle
    | isEOF <- hIsEOF fileHandle = []
    | otherwise                  = [hGetLine fileHandle] ++ readLines fileHandle

openDict :: IO Handle
openDict = do
    putStr "Enter file path: "
    filePath <- getLine
    openFile filePath ReadMode
```

Here is the error:

```
Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
    Expected type: IO (IO String)
      Actual type: [IO String]
    In the return type of a call of `readLines'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: readLines fileHandle
    In the expression:
      do { fileHandle <- openDict;
           readLines fileHandle;
           putStr "End of program" }
```

So basically, how can I store these strings from IO in a list?

Comment: `[IO String]` doesn't make a lot of sense here. (This is not to say it doesn't make sense at all). Try working with `IO [String]`.

Comment: Also `| isEOF <- hIsEOF fileHandle` doesn't mean what you think it means. It does not actually check for EOF, it just *binds* `hIsEOF` which you are supposed to use later. This syntax makes sense for monads like Maybe, but not for IO. See [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Haskell/guards.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `readLines` function has several problems.

First, in this case you do not want to return a `[IO String]`. This would be a list of IO actions such as `[print 1 >> return "a", print 2 >> return "b"]` which is not what you want. You need a single IO action returning a list of `String`s, so you need to use `IO [String]`.

Second, the pattern guard `isEof <- hIsEOF fileHandle` is checking whether the value returned by `hIsEOF` (which is an IO action) is of the form `isEOF`, where `isEOF` is a variable being defined right now. Of course *anything* is of the form `var`, since a variable can be anything. So the test is always true, and not meaningful: it does not even run the IO action, for instance.

Third, the way you combine the list constructors and IO actions follows the current wrong type,
so it is quite confusing.

A quite verbose way to achieve this would be instead:

```
readLines :: Handle -> IO [String]
readLines fileHandle = do
   eof <- hIsEOF fileHandle
   if eof then return []
          else do line <- hGetLine fileHandle
                  rest <- readLines fileHandle
                  return (line:rest)
```

The last lines can be shortened a bit using `Applicative` syntax:

```
import Control.Applicative
readLines2 :: Handle -> IO [String]
readLines2 fileHandle = do
   eof <- hIsEOF fileHandle
   if eof then return []
          else (:) <$> hGetLine fileHandle <*> readLines2 fileHandle
```

A short version can be instead obtained by reading everything in the file and splitting into lists after that using the `lines` library function.

```
import Control.Applicative
readLines3 :: Handle -> IO [String]
readLines3 fileHandle = lines <$> hGetContents fileHandle
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the errors in my code and ways to fix them. I have decided upon the library function as chosen solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `readLines` that you likely really want.

```
readLines :: Handle -> IO [String]
readLines h = do
    isEOF <- hIsEOF h -- need to access isEOF directly, without monad, see comment about the bind
    case isEOF of
        True -> return [] -- the return adds the IO monad to the [String] type
        False -> do
            line <- hGetLine h -- need to access line separately without monad
            lines <- readLines h -- recurse down
            return $ line ++ lines -- return adds back the IO monad
```